# Twitter integration iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, twitter, share

I am looking for a simple method to allow the user to share their score using Twitter. Originally I just opened a Twitter share URL in Mobile Safari to make the Tweet, however I can't seem to find a valid Twitter share URL. What would you suggest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at MGTwitterEngine. It's what MOST people I know of are using for twitter integration in their iPhone apps.

Answer (score 0):

For just sharing, try ShareKit: http://getsharekit.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is My FACEBOOK and TWITTER framework with basic app
https://github.com/comonitos/CM_TwitterFacebook_integrator